# How do I bind a model propery to table row selector in SAPUI5?

Tags: binding, sapui5

I'm using a Sap.M.Table, which should have a column of checkboxes bound to data. The Checkbox that shows up with MultiToggle selection seems to be a prettier solution all around, but how do I bind that particular checkbox (i.e. the 'row is selected' property) to my boolean property in my model?

I can't find any information about this seemingly simple thing anywhere.

---

My table is currently setup with a rows aggregation, and Column definitions that contain templates. I did try changing the rows aggregation to an items aggregation and then moved the content of my templates to the cells aggregation from the Items element in the xml, but as soon as I included the Items element, I got the 404 on sap.m.Items.js

```
  <tab:Table
    rows="{
                  path: '/Items'
              }"
    selectionMode="None"
    visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
    class="sapUiNoMargin"
    >
    <tab:columns>
      <tab:Column width="4rem" sortProperty="StatusBool">
        <Label text="Book" />
        <tab:template>
          <Checkbox selected="{Selected}" enabled="{StatusBool}" select="OnBookSelect" />
        </tab:template>
      </tab:Column>
      <tab:Column width="6rem" sortProperty="ProdOrder">
        <Label text="Production Order" />
        <tab:template>
          <Button text="{ProdOrder}" icon="sap-icon://inspection" width="100%" visible="{=!!${ProdOrder}}" press="OnProdOrderPress" />
        </tab:template>
      </tab:Column>
      <tab:Column width="14rem" sortProperty="ItemCode">
        <Label text="Item Code" />
        <tab:template>
          <Label text="{ItemCode}" />
        </tab:template>
      </tab:Column>
      <tab:Column width="10rem" sortProperty="Op">
        <Label text="Op" />
        <tab:template>
          <Label text="{Op}" />
        </tab:template>
      </tab:Column>
      <tab:Column width="8rem" sortProperty="PlanQty">
        <Label text="Planned Time" />
        <tab:template>
          <Label text="{PlanQty}" />
        </tab:template>
      </tab:Column>
    </tab:Columns>
  </tab:Table>
```

Comment: I think it takes the 'selected' value from the item

Comment: That definitely doesn't work with a Sap.M.Table, neither 'Selected', nor 'selected' works for me.

Comment: indeed youre right, you need to bind it to the ColumnListItem <ColumnListItem selected="{selected}" > ...

Comment: Hmm, I'm using OpenUI5 V1.46, and I get "Error: failed to load 'sap/m/items.js' so I guess that something changed.

Comment: you need to declare the columns in columns aggregation first. if you share som code I can drill further

Comment: As far as I can tell 'sap.ui.table' has the multi-select checkbox column, but 'sap.m.table' doesn't appear to. Also sap.m.table binds items aggregation whereas sap.ui.table binds rows. I'm not sure that the ColumnListItem has any implication on 'sap.ui.table', and that's the one that I'm using.